# How do I add a cell by click on add that will take TextField value and create a cell with that text in that tableview like below image in Swift/Obj-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

[image]

```swift
cell.addIconImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(addCell(_:"test"))))
```

I want to add a cell dynamically by click on plus button that would take TextField value of first cell and create a cell with that text and append below in that tableview like above image in Swift/Obj-C.
My plan was to take that value from TextField and pass that through addCell method.So I can append that text in an array and reload table again. Unfortunately it's not possible to pass params by #selector(method).

Comment: Why have you added the UITextField and add button in the cell? Why not move it to a separate view or make it a table/section header?

Comment: I did based on your suggestion by using section footer view. It's working 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the `cell`, create a separate view or a header view for the `textField` and `addButton`.

After doing that, you can simply fetch the `text` from `textField` and add it to the dataSource and then reload the `tableView`.

```
@IBAction func addCell(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let text = self.textField.text, !text.isEmpty {
        self.arr.append(text)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```